# How to report and integrate Extent or Junit report to "For loop" test scenarios and add assertion report Pass and Fail

Tags: java, selenium, junit, reporting, build-automation

I am automating e-commerce website. I am using JUNIT-Selenium framework.
Their are two files i am working with, first is the "TestCase.java" where my test steps are mentioned, aslo to start automation i run this file and second file is "TestMain.java" which has validation methods which will used by First file to verify and input the data in UI (mostly using If ..else validation).

First file consist of Automation initiation code, which uses Hashmap for reading the excel, extent report initiation and flush and use methods from testMain.java for input of data and validation through if... else statement.

TestCase.java looks like this:

```
public class TestCase extends AppTest {

private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Override
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    preparation = new Prep();
    application = new AppToTest();
    user = new Environment();
}

@Test
public void testLAP_Creamix() throws Exception {
    try {
        launchMainApplication();

        Test_frMain Test_frMainPage = new Test_frMain(tool, test, user, application);

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> win = CreamixWindowsDataset.main();
        SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(win.keySet());
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("Test_Report.html");
        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

        ExtentTest test1 = extent.createTest("Creamix test");

        for (String i : keys) {
            System.out.println("########### Test = " + win.get(i).get(0) + " ###########");
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.EnterTaille(win.get(i).get(1));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectCONFIGURATION(win.get(i).get(2));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectPLANVASQUE(win.get(i).get(3));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectCOULEUR(win.get(i).get(4));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectPOIGNEES(win.get(i).get(5));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectTYPE_DE_MEUBLE(win.get(i).get(6));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectCHOISISSEZ(win.get(i).get(7));

            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCE(win.get(i).get(8));(FROM HERE Validation Starts)
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITY(win.get(i).get(9));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCETwo(win.get(i).get(10));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYTwo(win.get(i).get(11));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCEThree(win.get(i).get(12));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYThree(win.get(i).get(13));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCEFour(win.get(i).get(14));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYFour(win.get(i).get(15));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCEFive(win.get(i).get(16));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYFive(win.get(i).get(17));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCESix(win.get(i).get(18));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYSix(win.get(i).get(19));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCESeven(win.get(i).get(20));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYSeven(win.get(i).get(21));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyPanierPrice(win.get(i).get(22));
            Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyECO_PARTPrice(win.get(i).get(23));

            Lapeyre_frMainPage.ClickCREAMIXReinit();(Reset button to test next scenario)

            test1.pass("Scenario " + win.get(i).get(0) + " is passed");
            System.out.println("########### Test End ##############");
            extent.flush();----------(Extent report over)

        }

        test.setResult("pass");
    } catch (AlreadyRunException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

}

@Override
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}
```

}

(Please note one loop is one scenario where im customizing and validating price of the product and then clicking reset button to next scenario for doing same)

And,

"TestMain.java" from where i am using methods to validate

one of the method is shown below

```
public void VerifyREFERENCE(String REF_1) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Verifying reference article");
    if (REF_1.equals("SKIP")) {
        System.out.println("SKIPPED");
    } else {
        WebElement referenceOne = tool.searchUsingXPath("//tbody//tr[1]//td//div[2]");
        String Ref1 = referenceOne.getText().trim();
        System.out.println("ref 1 is " + Ref1);
        if (Ref1.equals("Ref. de l'article : " + REF_1)) {
            System.out.println("Reference 1 is correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Reference 1 is incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using extent report in TestCase.java(Please check above code) to report my scenarios, but the problem is It shows all test case as PASS and if any failure occurs it doesn't report(it terminates).

Reason being i have not used assertions anywhere, BUT HOW CAN I APPLY SUCH ASSERTIONS IN THIS FRAMEWORK

TO SUMMARIZE:

1- I need to add price validation check in report
2- i tried of using this line in TestCase.java **"assertEquals("Verify REFERENCE 1", win.get(i).get(8), Lapeyre_frMainPage.GetREFERENCE());"** but i cant use assertion in TestCase.java(it wont allow me).
3- Please show me alternative way to report PASS and FAIL for such frameworks, where in extent report i can able to show price mismatch between excel and UI.

Comment: Your `TestCase` extends `AppTest`. What is `AppTest`?

Comment: AppTest consist of other methods and webdriver initiation

Comment: I am getting return as "true" every time, from my verifyREFERENCE method, but now i can able to fail test case now, need to know why my method is return as true?

Comment: Maybe it always returns true because your test case passes? Do you have failing test data? Also, you should probably comment against the answer instead of the original question, if your comment is related to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can only expect `assertEquals()` to work if your TestCase class extends junit test, or if you implement the method yourself in your code.

In any case, you seem to be trying to use `ExtentReports`. I am not experienced with that library, but according to the [javadoc for ExtentTest](http://www.extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/javadoc/com/aventstack/extentreports/ExtentTest.html), it appears that you are expected to call `.pass()` or `.fail()` yourself based on the outcome of your test.

In your TestCase, I believe you want to try to maintain a boolean to track if the test has passed or not.

The first step would be to modify `VerifyREFERENCE()` to return a boolean indicating if it passed or failed, instead of being void.

```
public boolean VerifyREFERENCE(String REF_1) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Verifying reference article");
    if (REF_1.equals("SKIP")) {
        System.out.println("SKIPPED");
    } else {
        WebElement referenceOne = tool.searchUsingXPath("//tbody//tr[1]//td//div[2]");
        String Ref1 = referenceOne.getText().trim();
        System.out.println("ref 1 is " + Ref1);
        if (Ref1.equals("Ref. de l'article : " + REF_1)) {
            System.out.println("Reference 1 is correct");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Reference 1 is incorrect");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your TestCase, initialise a boolean to true just before the loop. Inside the loop, perform a logical AND (&&) with the return value of each `VerifyREFERENCE()` call. Finally, after the loop finishes, test the value of the boolean, and pass or fail the ExtentTest as appropriate:

```
ExtentTest test1 = extent.createTest("Creamix test");
boolean passed = true;

for (String i : keys) {
    System.out.println("########### Test = " + win.get(i).get(0) + " ###########");
    Lapeyre_frMainPage.EnterTaille(win.get(i).get(1));
    ....
    Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectCHOISISSEZ(win.get(i).get(7));

    passed = passed && Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCE(win.get(i).get(8));(FROM HERE Validation Starts)
    passed = passed && Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITY(win.get(i).get(9));
    ...
    passed = passed && Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyECO_PARTPrice(win.get(i).get(23));

    Lapeyre_frMainPage.ClickCREAMIXReinit();(Reset button to test next scenario)

    if(passed) {
       test1.pass("Scenario " + win.get(i).get(0) + " is passed");
    } else {
       test1.fail("Scenario " + win.get(i).get(0) + " is failed");
    }
    System.out.println("########### Test End ##############");
    extent.flush();----------(Extent report over)
}
```

Comment: Excuse me for the previous comment, let me summarize it, actually i can see my console in jenkins that my method is showing reference didnt matched, but even after returning false why cant my test step "Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCE(win.get(i).get(8))" is not taking it as false????

Comment: Please note, In my test case my test step is failing and i want to show that in extent report, that this test case is failed due to reference number is not matching from excel with the help of public boolean VerifyREFERENCE(String REF_1)  method.

Comment: It is strange, I hope I am understanding you correctly. One suggestion I can make is to focus on only one of the checks, and remove or comment out the rest of them until you get the expected behaviour from the single one `win.get(i).get(8)`. In your TestCase loop, after calling `VerifyREFERENCE()`, do a `System.out.println("VerifyREFERENCE 8 is " + passed);`. What value does that show in the console?

Comment: Still same, Extent report is showing me the test case is passed.
while the logs show me as 
Verifying reference article
ref 1 is Ref. de l'article : 1241998
Reference 1 is incorrect
########### Test End ##############